# What would this element be called in c++ Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Im making a GUI for my program and currently trying to figure out what this component would be called.

[image]

Does anyone know what this would be called or how I could achieve this effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `QListWidget` to your ui form from the Qt Designer toolbox window. And click right on it then click changeStylesheet... then paste this:

```
QListWidget {
color:white;
border:1px solid transparent;
border-radius:10px;
padding:0px;
background:#F6911B;
show-decoration-selected: 1;
}

QListWidget::item{
border-top:1px solid #E98919;
padding: 15px;
}

QListWidget::item:hover {
border-top:1px solid #E98919;
background-color: #F6911B;
color:white;
}

QListWidget::item:selected:!active {
border-top:1px solid #E98919;
background-color:white;
color:#F6911B;
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: screenshot of the styled list]

To learn how style sheets work in relation to `QListView`, see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qlistview

Comment: To add images to your questions or answers, use imgur hosting provided in the question/answer editor. The third-party site links are atrocious.

Answer (score 1):

[QListWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html) is a listbox similar to the image you posted.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a QMenu with QActions attached to it. First you create a QAction, connect with the related slot, and attach to QMenu. Then attach the menu to a QWidget (or its subclass)